# How to convert uint16_t into char array in c?

Tags: c

have the following data

```
uint16_t a[1] = { 0x1111 };
```

I want to convert to `char b[]` as:

```
char b[1] = { 0x1111 };
```

How can I do it in a C program?

Comment: How do you want to squash the 16 bits into 8 bits?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `char b[1]` is not large enough to hold two bytes of a `uint16_t a[1]`.

If you want to allocate a copy then memcpy is a way:

```
char b[sizeof(a)];
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
```

If you want to alias it as a char type you could just cast the pointer:

```
char * b = (char *)a;
```

Comment: There's little point in guessing. It would probably better to wait until the asker clears up the confusion

Answer (score 0):

`0x1111` is greater than the maximum value a character (of type `char` ... ie: `uint8_t`) can take... so possibly you need an array with two, like: `char b[2] = { 0x11, 0x11 };`